# i edit my file in localhost it perfectly worked.but after up my site it shows error and not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working in php **codeigniter**. When I edit my file on localhost it works perfectly.

But after having uploaded my site, it is showing an error (as shown below) and not working properly.

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/innofeast014/public_html/caremykiddie.com/demo/hospital/controllers/patient_register.php:664)
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 688

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/innofeast014/public_html/caremykiddie.com/demo/hospital/controllers/patient_register.php:664)
>
> Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 542

Any idea concerning the error please?

Comment: You forgot to attach the code of `patient_register.php`. In line 6 of it you print something on the screen. This breaks subsequently executed code.

Comment: We can't help you unless you post your code.

Comment: Check carefully may be there is any space or line before the php tag of you any controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error might come up if you have any spaces before your first PHP tag. Can you post your index.php file or whatever works as your entry file